# htaccess rewrite working offline on WAMP but not online on linux host

Tags: linux, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I'm just going to explain my problem here :

```
http://mysite.com/movie/20000
```

should be rewritten to

```
http://mysite.com/movie.php?id=20000
```

my htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)$ movie.php?id=$1
```

On my localhost WAMP installation this works fine, but when I put it online on my linux host it doesn't completely work. It does go to the movie.php page, but it seems it gives no GET parameter id.

**Edit :**

if I use

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^movie([0-9]+)$ movie.php?id=$1
```

then

```
http://mysite.com/movie20000
```

Goes to the correct page, but I would like `/movie/20000` and not just `/movie20000`

It also seems that my host automatically rewrites a visit to `mysite.com/movie` to `mysite.com/movie.php`

Comment: Try getting more information by adding: `RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"` and on the next line `RewriteLogLevel 3` to your config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for a long time, and pulling some of my lovely hair out I found the solution.

I just added

```
Options -MultiViews
```

to my htaccess file and that fixed it.

Why? Because .php was being added to urls without an extension, which I really did not need.

Comment: I found your post after 3 hours of pulling _my_ lovely hair out. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
RewriteRule ^movie/([0-9]+)$ http://mysite.com/movie.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Don't forget the [NC, L] it means Case insensitive, last rule... If you don't, it will continue to process through your htaccess rules, maybe triggering other ones.

Still, the stuff below is good advice.... :)

Check to see if the Rewrite module is loading with apache.  Look for this line in the httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Check to see if your apache config allows for .htaccess files for your system or in the virtual host definition.

Also, test with a simpler rewrite catch all and test that alone to see if it's working at all like this (get rid of everything else in your htaccess file to limit the test):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com [L,R=301]
```

Any request to your site should go to google if the configuration for apache is correctly set.

Comment: That all works correctly, I updated my question with some extra info.

Comment: You're sure about that $0 ? Doesn't seem to work, while $1 did it in the past. I asked my host the question, maybe they had the same question before.

Comment: @gl3nn My, bad... user the full URL in the redirect and $1... that should work.  See the answer above.